# Shell script producing the escaping character (\) with escaped double qoutes

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, terraform

**Short version:** 
why would shell script produce the escaping character () embedded (but not visible) in its produced String?

**Detailed version:**

I have a script which generates a *Terraform* command and executes it. The command generation involves using variables to substitute computed values as below:

```
...
AWS_VM_NUMBER=1
types="{"
array_limit=$((AWS_VM_NUMBER - 1))
for ((i = 0; i <= $array_limit; i++));
do
  var=AWS_INSTANCE_TYPE_${i+1}
  types=${types}"\"$i\"=\"${!var}\","
done
instance_types_array=${types%,}"}"

echo $instance_types_array ## prints {"0"="t2.small"} which is the correct fromat

...
# Now,  executing a terraform command like this (please ignore the other variables as they exist else where in the code)

terraform apply -var \'access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY\' \
-var \'secret_key=$AWS_SECRET_KEY\' \
-var \'instance_count=$AWS_VM_NUMBER\' \
-var \'region=$AWS_REGION\' \
-var \'instance_types=$instance_types_array\'
```

When the terraform command is executed, I get the following error:

> invalid value "'instance_types={\"0\"=\"t2.small\"}'" for flag -var: Cannot parse value for variable ("{\"0\"=\"t2.small\"}'") as valid HCL: At 1:21: illegal char

If I put the command in a variable and echo it, it prints without the backslash. However, if I copy it and execute it manually in terminal, I get the same error. It will only work if I delete the double quotes and type them back manually!

Comment: yes it did, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the enclosing double-braces(`{` and `}`) also before passing to the `terraform` command. To avoid escaping the characters manually you can leave it to `printf()` function in `bash` which can do the required escape sequences.

Use the command with `-v` to apply the escaping done to a new variable and pass that to the `terraform` command

```
printf -v esc_instance_types "%q" "${instance_types_array}"
```

Now the `esc_instances_types` will have a value when printed as

```
printf "%s\n" "${esc_instances_types}"
\{\"0\"=\"t2.small\"\}
```

You can now pass this variable to the command you need. See [printf() - Format Strings](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) for more information.